# Different variants of method depending on parameters

Tags: java, function, types, formatter

I have classes called ctdl_User, ctdl_Device and ctdl_Options.

I have a function that saves ctdl_User objects using the binary formatter, and another that loads them. However the functions specifically expect to take and return User objects, and I want to use this function to load other objects of mine.

How do I go about changing what types the functions will take? Here is the save and load functions...

```
public ctdl_User Load()
    {
        ctdl_User loadedUsr = new ctdl_User();
        string DataFileSave = Settings.Default.savePath + "\\testuserfile.dat";
        FileStream dataStr = new FileStream(DataFileSave, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter frmtr = new BinaryFormatter();
        loadedUsr = (ctdl_User) frmtr.Deserialize(dataStr);
        dataStr.Close();
        return loadedUsr;
    }

public static void Save(ctdl_User usr)
    {
        string DataFileSave = Settings.Default.savePath + "\\testuserfile.dat";
            File.Delete(DataFileSave);
            FileStream dataStr = new FileStream(DataFileSave, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryFormatter frmtr = new BinaryFormatter();
            frmtr.Serialize(dataStr, usr);
            dataStr.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following demonstrates an approach using generics in C#:

```
public static T Load<T>() where T : new()
{
    T loadedUsr = new T();
    string DataFileSave = Settings.Default.savePath + "\\testuserfile.dat";
    FileStream dataStr = new FileStream(DataFileSave, FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter frmtr = new BinaryFormatter();
    loadedUsr = (T) frmtr.Deserialize(dataStr);
    dataStr.Close();
    return loadedUsr;
}

public static void Save<T>(T usr)
{
    string DataFileSave = Settings.Default.savePath + "\\testuserfile.dat";
    File.Delete(DataFileSave);
    FileStream dataStr = new FileStream(DataFileSave, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter frmtr = new BinaryFormatter();
    frmtr.Serialize(dataStr, usr);
    dataStr.Close();
}
```

Note the use of the [new() constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) in the `Load()` method.
Here's an example of calling these methods:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ctdl_User user = new ctdl_User();
    user.name = "Alice";
    Save<ctdl_User>(user);
    ctdl_User user2 = Load<ctdl_User>();
    Console.WriteLine(user2.name);

    ctdl_Device device = new ctdl_Device();
    device.type = "printer";
    Save<ctdl_Device>(device);
    ctdl_Device device2 = Load<ctdl_Device>();
    Console.WriteLine(device2.type);
}
```

For completeness, here are the stub classes I used to test this code:

```
[Serializable()]
class ctdl_User
{
    public string name;
}

[Serializable()]
class ctdl_Device
{
    public string type;
}
```

Edit: added code to `Main()` that saves and loads a device, as well as a user.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Java you can just overload the method following this scheme:

```
    public static void Load(Type1 obj)
    {
        //do sth with object of type Type1
    }

    public static void Load(Type2 obj)
    {
        //do sth with object of type Type2
    }

    //...etc
```

Also if you have common code for it that can be used for objects of another types you can exrtact this code to one methode that treat overloaded methods as facade

```
    private static void doLoad(Object obj)
    {
        //the common code
    }

    public static void Load(Type1 obj)
    {
        doLoad(obj); // or something else...
    }

    public static void Load(Type2 obj)
    {
        doLoad(obj); // or something else...
    }

    //...etc
```

You can read more about [overloading methods in Java here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)